# Tish'a Ve'arba'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred forty-nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: Everyone, if you like this series, please up-vote the first in the series, http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/378 — let's get the asker a "great question" badge http://mi.yodeya.com/badges

Comment: :) Thanks, but that's really not necessary. If you like this series (or anything else on m.y) and want to pay it a real tribute, share it with your friends, social networks, newspaper, etc. There are some buttons to make that easier over here -------------------------------------------------------------------->

Comment: That, too!  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

149 are the chapters in Tehillim that aren't titled "tehillah." (Ps. 145 is the only one, and apparently it gave its title to the entire book!)